# Проект перестал компилироваться на Ios в Xamarin Live Player

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Начал только разбираться в `Visual Studio 2017`, в частности работе с `Xamarin Forms`. Установил на телефон `Xamarin Live Player`, но не могу развернуть даже пустой проект с единственной надписью - "Добро пожаловать в Xamarin Forms."
 Притом на UWP на винде и компилится, и разворачивается на ура.
Скрин ошибок прилагаю.

[image: Ошибки компиляции]

Comment: Кстати, все веселье это началось после глобально обновления Visual Studio, до обновления все отлично работало.

Answer (score 0):

Пробовал Live Player и не смог заставить его работать стабильно даже на самых простых проектах. На мой взгляд единственный рабочий вариант сейчас это LiveXAML До 5 форм он вроде бесплатный, но в целом лицензия стоит денег. Я купил лицензию и не пожалел ни разу. Огромная экономия времени.

Кроме того LiveXAML не имеет ограничений и работает буквально со всем - с кастомными рендерами, Fody, Realm